# for loops - why does range(len()) cause TypeError: int not subscriptable in this case?

Tags: python, loops

I'm working on looping through a JSON response and I'm trying to figure out why in this case below I get a `TypeError: 'int' not subscriptable`.

```
list = []
for i in range(len(json_data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results'])):
        list.append(i['FastestLap']['Time']['time'])

print(list)
```

I got around this by just doing a `try`/`except` block but I would rather know the length of what I'm iterating over. I tried reading some of the posts on here from other folks regarding this but couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: overriding keyword `list` for your variable is a terrible idea...

Comment: @Julien I'm just practicing and was using very obvious names to know what is going on as I read it out loud. I understand that it is not a good idea. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because `i` is an integer in this: `list.append(i['FastestLap']['Time']['time'])`

try this:

```py
results = json_data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results']
for i in range(len(results)):
        list.append(results[i]['FastestLap']['Time']['time'])
```

It will get the `i`th item from the list.

Comment: More pythonic to do `for r in results:` and `list.append(r['FastestLap']['Time']['time'])`...

Comment: @Julien yes, but that doesn't answer his question well enough imo. it was specifically why `i` was not scriptable

Comment: @gear4 ah okay! So in your code snippet, "i" is now acting as an index position instead of an integer?

Comment: @krisbkreeme yes indeed, because when you do `len` you're getting the total length, and when you do `range` you get the entire range (0 to len), and then you loop over *that*

Comment: @gear4 while this does technically solve that problem, it now raises the problem of KeyError: 'FastestLap' which I thought was because I was trying to iterate over it one too many times, which is why I thought range(len() would solve it. Am I wrong here?

Comment: yes. you have to make sure that `FastestLap` exists in the `results[i]` object - it will raise that keyerror otherwise. if `results[i]` didn't exist, then it would be an IndexError

Answer (score 0):

You have taken the `len` inside range, so you'll get the value for i as `int` from `0` to `len(whateverItIs) - 1`. And inside the loop you're treating `i` as a dict. The “typeerror: 'int' object is not subscriptable” error is raised when you try to access an integer as if it were a subscriptable object, like a list or a dictionary.

That's why you are getting that error in this line:

```
list.append(i['FastestLap']['Time']['time'])
```

To overcome the problem, you can do as follows:

```
dict_val = json_data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results']
for element in dict_val:
    list.append(element['FastestLap']['Time']['time'])
```